# How to change hover label on star-rating-comp in angular?

Tags: angular

I spent two days to figure this thing out but without result. 
What a problem? When i hover mouse into first,second... fifth star the label "star-filled" appears (first image). If i hover mouse very closely to star but not on star (between them) my title from html appears. But i want to set my own label when mouse over star (instead of standart "star-filled"). Somebody please help me to figure out where is this thing should be changed??? Because i haven't found any settings for this label in the code at all.

[image]
[image]

```
     <div title="mytitle">
      <star-rating-comp [starType]="'svg'" 
                        [showHalfStars]="true" 
                        [rating]="cards[questionNumber].rating" 
                        [readOnly]="true" 
                        title="mytitle">
      </star-rating-comp>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz for your case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hard coded `<title>` in the actual svg file that would need removed. If you do a file search for `star-rating.icons.svg` you'll find `<title>star-filled</title>` in the actual [svg source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BioPhoton/angular-star-rating/0e41b3f64da903e9f4db7f7c96d01e0aa5a84127/libs/angular-star-rating/src/assets/images/star-rating.icons.svg). Along with other titles in the defs that would cause the same effect.

```
<symbol id="star-filled" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
            <title>star-filled</title>               <----- *** Your Culprit
            <path class="path-star-filled"
.........
```

Since it's in [a repo](https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-star-rating) I would suggest just cloning it, maybe even submit a pull request to the original author since those titles in there will likely cause issues for other folks as well. Cheers.